# WebRTC's ReplaceTrack suddenly not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

This replaceTrack function previously working with Firefox suddenly not working in Firefox, Chrome has no issue.

I've tested with the latest Firefox & developer Firefox, both don't seem to work. May I know what causes this issue?

```
peer.getSenders().map(function (sender) {
    sender.replaceTrack(stream.getTracks().find(function (track) {
        return track.kind === sender.track.kind;
    }));
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/yukbn0ep/).

Comment: Hi @jib, it's strange on my side and also I didn't see any error messages appear on the Firefox console, besides, I also reinstalled Firefox, but still having the same issue, thanks.

Comment: Does that fiddle I link to not work for you? In Firefox? Chrome? Check the ☐
 scramble button.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the fiddle link, I've tried on both browsers Chrome & Firefox, both working. Unfortunately, it's not working on my call app when I try to replaceTrack with other source of stream.

Comment: @jib, Finally, I found that the problem arises from the tracks.enabled set to false. ReplaceTrack works in Chrome without resetting the tracks.enabled to true. After resetting the tracks.enabled to true, everything works perfectly in Firefox, appreciate and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem arises from the tracks.enabled set to false. replaceTrack works in Chrome even without resetting the tracks.enabled to true. After resetting the tracks.enabled to true, everything works perfectly in Firefox.

```
var tracks = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
tracks.enabled = true;
```

Comment: Glad it's working. If you're able to reproduce a difference in behavior in Chrome here compared to Firefox, then please consider [filing a bug on Chrome](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entryafterlogin).